# Run a task when any file in given directory is changed in SBT?

Tags: sbt

Is there a way to run a task on every code change in a given directory? Preferably, something that works well with `~` operator in SBT so that I could do:

```
~jadeCompile
```

to run custom `jadeCompile` task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [triggered execution](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/triggered.html). You can configure the watched directory using the `watchSources` setting. This is a bit trickier as only Scala source files will be watched by default, so we need to specify an appropriate [path finder](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Paths.html#path-finders):

```
watchSources <++= baseDirectory map { path => 
    ((path / "src/main/jade") ** "*.jade").get }
```

The `watchSources` setting is not scoped, so you will need to watch all sources at once. Then you just have to run:

```
~jadeCompile
```

Comment: unfortunately, this only seems to trigger the task if the file that changed ends with .scala :(

Comment: @Arg you're right, I fixed the answer with properly tested code :)